# Calculate Haralick features using jfeaturelib

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I want to calculate **haralick** features in android using **jfeaturelib**(*which is basically for java*) but I came to know that there is no implementation of **ImageIO** or **BufferedImage** in android as these are used in calculating haralick features in bellow code. These are only available in pure JAVA .

```
public void haralickFeatures(){
    InputStream stream = HaralickDemo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg");
    ColorProcessor image = new ColorProcessor(ImageIO.read(stream));

    // initialize the descriptor
    Haralick descriptor = new Haralick();

    // run the descriptor and extract the features
    descriptor.run(image);

    // obtain the features
    List<double[]> features = descriptor.getFeatures();

    // print the features to system out
    for (double[] feature : features) {
        System.out.println(Arrays2.join(feature, ", ", "%.5f"));
      }
   }
```

Is there a way to calculate haralick features in android. Any code example will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you cannot use jfeaturelib to calculate **haralick features** because this library use certain classes that are only implemented in pure java but not android. 
You can use my code which I had taken from jfeaturelib and modified it to fit to use for android.

- *First you have to create a java class in your android project and name it what you want(in my case I name it as GLCM)*

  ```
  public class GLCM {
           static int totalPixels=0;
           /**
            * The number of gray values for the textures
            */
           private final int NUM_GRAY_VALUES = 32;
           /**
            * p_(x+y) statistics
            */
           private final double[] p_x_plus_y = new double[2 * NUM_GRAY_VALUES - 1];
           /**
            * p_(x-y) statistics
            */
           private final double[] p_x_minus_y = new double[NUM_GRAY_VALUES];
           /**
            * row mean value
            */
  private double mu_x = 0;
  /**
   * column mean value
   */
  private double mu_y = 0;
  /**
   * row variance
   */
  private double var_x = 0;
  /**
   * column variance
   */
  private double var_y = 0;
  /**
   * HXY1 statistics
   */
  private double hx = 0;
  /**
   * HXY2 statistics
   */
  private double hy = 0;
  /**
   * HXY1 statistics
   */
  private double hxy1 = 0;
  /**
   * HXY2 statistics
   */
  private double hxy2 = 0;
  /**
   * p_x statistics
   */
  private final double[] p_x = new double[NUM_GRAY_VALUES];
  /**
   * p_y statistics
   */
  private final double[] p_y = new double[NUM_GRAY_VALUES];
  // -
  public List<double[]> data;
  public int haralickDist;
  double[] features = null;
  static byte[] imageArray;
  public void addData(double[] data) {

      this.data.add(data);
  }
  public List<double[]> getFeatures() {
      return data;
  }
  public void process(Bitmap b) {

      features = new double[14];

      Coocurrence coocurrence = new Coocurrence(b, NUM_GRAY_VALUES, this.haralickDist);
      coocurrence.calculate();
      double[][] cooccurrenceMatrix = coocurrence.getCooccurrenceMatrix();
      double meanGrayValue = coocurrence.getMeanGrayValue();


      normalize(cooccurrenceMatrix, coocurrence.getCooccurenceSums());

      calculateStatistics(cooccurrenceMatrix);
      double[][] p = cooccurrenceMatrix;
      double[][] Q = new double[NUM_GRAY_VALUES][NUM_GRAY_VALUES];
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; i++) {
          double sum_j_p_x_minus_y = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; j++) {
              double p_ij = p[i][j];

              sum_j_p_x_minus_y += j * p_x_minus_y[j];

              features[0] += p_ij * p_ij;
              features[2] += i * j * p_ij - mu_x * mu_y;
              features[3] += (i - meanGrayValue) * (i - meanGrayValue) * p_ij;
              features[4] += p_ij / (1 + (i - j) * (i - j));
              features[8] += p_ij * log(p_ij);

              // feature 13
              if (p_ij != 0 && p_x[i] != 0) { // would result in 0
                  for (int k = 0; k < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; k++) {
                      if (p_y[k] != 0 && p[j][k] != 0) { // would result in NaN
                          Q[i][j] += (p_ij * p[j][k]) / (p_x[i] * p_y[k]);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          features[1] += i * i * p_x_minus_y[i];
          features[9] += (i - sum_j_p_x_minus_y) * (i - sum_j_p_x_minus_y) * p_x_minus_y[i];
          features[10] += p_x_minus_y[i] * log(p_x_minus_y[i]);
      }

      // feature 13: Max Correlation Coefficient
      double[] realEigenvaluesOfQ = new Matrix(Q).eig().getRealEigenvalues();
      Arrays2.abs(realEigenvaluesOfQ);
      Arrays.sort(realEigenvaluesOfQ);
      features[13] = Math.sqrt(realEigenvaluesOfQ[realEigenvaluesOfQ.length - 2]);

      features[2] /= Math.sqrt(var_x * var_y);
      features[8] *= -1;
      features[10] *= -1;
      double maxhxhy = Math.max(hx, hy);
      if (Math.signum(maxhxhy) == 0) {
          features[11] = 0;
      } else {
          features[11] = (features[8] - hxy1) / maxhxhy;
      }
      features[12] = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.exp(-2 * (hxy2 - features[8])));

      for (int i = 0; i < 2 * NUM_GRAY_VALUES - 1; i++) {
          features[5] += i * p_x_plus_y[i];
          features[7] += p_x_plus_y[i] * log(p_x_plus_y[i]);

          double sum_j_p_x_plus_y = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < 2 * NUM_GRAY_VALUES - 1; j++) {
              sum_j_p_x_plus_y += j * p_x_plus_y[j];
          }
          features[6] += (i - sum_j_p_x_plus_y) * (i - sum_j_p_x_plus_y) * p_x_plus_y[i];
      }

      features[7] *= -1;
  }

  /**
   * Calculates the statistical properties.
   */
  private void calculateStatistics(double[][] cooccurrenceMatrix) {
      // p_x, p_y, p_x+y, p_x-y
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; j++) {
              double p_ij = cooccurrenceMatrix[i][j];

              p_x[i] += p_ij;
              p_y[j] += p_ij;

              p_x_plus_y[i + j] += p_ij;
              p_x_minus_y[Math.abs(i - j)] += p_ij;
          }
      }

      // mean and variance values
      double[] meanVar;
      meanVar = meanVar(p_x);
      mu_x = meanVar[0];
      var_x = meanVar[1];
      meanVar = meanVar(p_y);
      mu_y = meanVar[0];
      var_y = meanVar[1];

      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; i++) {
          // hx and hy
          hx += p_x[i] * log(p_x[i]);
          hy += p_y[i] * log(p_y[i]);

          // hxy1 and hxy2
          for (int j = 0; j < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; j++) {
              double p_ij = cooccurrenceMatrix[i][j];
              hxy1 += p_ij * log(p_x[i] * p_y[j]);
              hxy2 += p_x[i] * p_y[j] * log(p_x[i] * p_y[j]);
          }
      }
      hx *= -1;
      hy *= -1;
      hxy1 *= -1;
      hxy2 *= -1;
  }

  /**
   * Compute mean and variance of the given array
   *
   * @param a inut values
   * @return array{mean, variance}
   */
  private double[] meanVar(double[] a) {
      // VAR(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2
      // two-pass is numerically stable.
      double ex = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; i++) {
          ex += a[i];
      }
      ex /= a.length;
      double var = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRAY_VALUES; i++) {
          var += (a[i] - ex) * (a[i] - ex);
      }
      var /= (a.length - 1);

      return new double[]{ex, var};
  }

  /**
   * Returns the bound logarithm of the specified value.
   *
   * If Math.log would be Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0 is returned
   *
   * @param value the value for which the logarithm should be returned
   * @return the logarithm of the specified value
   */
  private double log(double value) {
      double log = Math.log(value);
      if (log == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
          log = 0;
      }
      return log;
  }

  /**
   * Normalizes the array by the given sum. by dividing each 2nd dimension
   * array componentwise by the sum.
   *
   * @param A
   * @param sum
   */
  private void normalize(double[][] A, double sum) {
      for (double[] A1 : A) {
          Arrays2.div(A1, sum);
      }
  }

  //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="getter/Setter">
  /**
   * Getter for haralick distributions
   *
   * @return haralick distributions
   */
  public int getHaralickDist() {
      return haralickDist;
  }

  /**
   * Setter for haralick distributions
   *
   * @param haralickDist int for haralick distributions (must be >= 1)
   */
  public void setHaralickDist(int haralickDist) {
      if (haralickDist <= 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("the distance for haralick must be >= 1 but was " + haralickDist);
      }
      this.haralickDist = haralickDist;
  }
  //</editor-fold>

  static class Coocurrence {

      /**
       * The number of gray values for the textures
       */
      private final int NUM_GRAY_VALUES;
      /**
       * The number of gray levels in an image
       */
      int GRAY_RANGES = 256;
      /**
       * The scale for the gray values for conversion rgb to gray values.
       */
      double GRAY_SCALE;
      /**
       * gray histogram of the image.
       */
      double[] grayHistogram;
      /**
       * Quantized gray values of each pixel of the image.
       *
       * Use int instead of byte as there is no unsigned byte in Java.
       * Otherwise you'll have a hard time using white = 255. Alternative:
       * replace with ImageJ ByteProcessor.
       */
      private final int[] grayValue;
      /**
       * mean gray value
       */
      private double meanGrayValue = 0;
      /**
       * The cooccurrence matrix
       */
      private final double[][] cooccurrenceMatrices;
      /**
       * The value for one increment in the gray/color histograms.
       */
      private final int HARALICK_DIST;
      private final Bitmap image;

      public Coocurrence(Bitmap b, int numGrayValues, int haralickDist) {
          this.NUM_GRAY_VALUES = numGrayValues;
          this.HARALICK_DIST = haralickDist;
          this.cooccurrenceMatrices = new double[NUM_GRAY_VALUES][NUM_GRAY_VALUES];
          this.image = b;
          totalPixels=b.getHeight()*b.getWidth();
          this.grayValue = new int[totalPixels];
      }

      void calculate() {
          this.GRAY_SCALE = (double) GRAY_RANGES / (double) NUM_GRAY_VALUES;
          this.grayHistogram = new double[GRAY_RANGES];

          calculateGreyValues();

          final int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
          final int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
          final int d = HARALICK_DIST;
          final int yOffset = d * imageWidth;
          int i, j, pos;

          // image is not empty per default
          for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
              for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
                  pos = imageWidth * y + x;

                  // horizontal neighbor: 0 degrees
                  i = x - d;
                  if (i >= 0) {
                      increment(grayValue[pos], grayValue[pos - d]);
                  }

                  // vertical neighbor: 90 degree
                  j = y - d;
                  if (j >= 0) {
                      increment(grayValue[pos], grayValue[pos - yOffset]);
                  }

                  // 45 degree diagonal neigbor
                  i = x + d;
                  j = y - d;
                  if (i < imageWidth && j >= 0) {
                      increment(grayValue[pos], grayValue[pos + d - yOffset]);
                  }

                  // 135 vertical neighbor
                  i = x - d;
                  j = y - d;
                  if (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                      increment(grayValue[pos], grayValue[pos - d - yOffset]);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      private void calculateGreyValues() {
          final int size = grayValue.length;
          double graySum = 0;
          for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
              int gray = imageArray[pos]&0xff;
              graySum += gray;
              grayValue[pos] = (int) (gray / GRAY_SCALE);  // quantized for texture analysis
              assert grayValue[pos] >= 0 : grayValue[pos] + " > 0 violated";
              grayHistogram[gray]++;
          }
          Arrays2.div(grayHistogram, size);
          meanGrayValue = Math.floor(graySum / size / GRAY_SCALE)*GRAY_SCALE;
      }

      /**
       * Incremets the coocurrence matrix at the specified positions (g1,g2)
       * and (g2,g1) if g1 and g2 are in range.
       *
       * @param g1 the gray value of the first pixel
       * @param g2 the gray value of the second pixel
       */
      private void increment(int g1, int g2) {
          cooccurrenceMatrices[g1][g2]++;
          cooccurrenceMatrices[g2][g1]++;
      }

      public double getMeanGrayValue() {
          return this.meanGrayValue;
      }

      public double[][] getCooccurrenceMatrix() {
          return this.cooccurrenceMatrices;
      }

      public double getCooccurenceSums() {
          // divide by R=8 neighbours
          // see p.613, §2 of Haralick paper
          return totalPixels * 8;
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Now create object of that GLCM class in your main activity or in activity you want

  ```
   GLCM glcm=new GLCM();
  ```
- Next step is to copy past this function in your main activity or in activity you want. This function extract feature as you have to pass an image as bitmap and this function will return **14 haralick features** in float array. Here is that function

  ```
  public void haralickFeatures(Bitmap b) throws IOException {
  glcm.haralickDist=1;
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); // what 90 does ??
  GLCM.imageArray=new byte[]{};
  GLCM.imageArray = stream.toByteArray();
  glcm.process(b);
  glcm.data = new ArrayList<>(1);
  glcm.addData(glcm.features);
  List<double[]> featuresHar=glcm.getFeatures();

  for (double[] feature : featuresHar) {
      featureString=Arrays2.join(feature, ",", "%.5f");
  }
  String[] featureStr=featureString.split(Pattern.quote(","));
  float[] featureFlot = new float[featureStr.length];
  for (int i=0;i<featureStr.length;i++){
      featureFlot[i]=Float.parseFloat(featureStr[i]);
     }
  //featureFlot is array that contain all 14 haralick features

   }
  ```